# Modelling a range constraint based on a value

Tags: linear-programming, mixed-integer-programming

I'm trying to model a constraint based on a range.
I have a lp variable $x_1$ with range $[0,60]$, and a binary variable $y_1$.

$y_1$ must be $1$ iff $x_1$ belongs to the range $[25,35]$.
How do I add this constraint?
I've tried this : $$x_1>25y_1, x_1 < 35+ 25(1-y_1).$$
While this ensures that $y_1$ is zero if $x_1$ is not in the required range, it does not ensure $y_1$ is $1$ otherwise.
I could try to maximize $y_1$, but was hoping that there would  be a way without having to depend on the solver for setting $y_1$ to $1$.

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: http://or.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Introduce two additional binary variables: $y_2=1$ iff $x_1 \ge 25$, and $y_3=1$ iff $x_1 \le 35$. Enforce these definitions with the following constraints:
$$\begin{align}
x_1 - 25 & \le My_2 \\
25 - x_1 & \le M(1-y_2) \\
35 - x_1 & \le My_3 \\
x_1 - 35 & \le M(1-y_3)
\end{align}$$
where $M$ is a large constant.

Now require $y_1=1$ iff $y_2=y_3=1$:
$$\begin{align}
y_1 & \ge y_2 + y_3 - 1 \\
y_1 & \le y_2 \\
y_1 & \le y_3
\end{align}$$

Note that these constraints might fail at the boundaries, if $x_1=25$ or $35$. Hopefully this is OK. If not, [this answer on OR.SE](https://or.stackexchange.com/a/34/38) might help with the equality cases.

Comment: Yeah this solution works,thanks !

Comment: @SuhasPai Great. Don't forget you can accept and/or upvote the answer if you are so inclined.