# Modelling a different ranges constraint based on a value

Tags: linear-programming, mixed-integer-programming

I want to set a variable $D$ to a certain value based on another variable $X$ depending on the range of $X$ as follows:

if $0<x \le100  , D =2$
if $100<x \le200  , D =5.3$
if $200<x \le300  , D =1.2$

I know how to do a value based on one range (as was answered for different question "[Modelling a range constraint based on a value](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3260511/modelling-a-range-constraint-based-on-a-value/3260529#3260529?newreg=36bb639ce38d4e8b8c97d44fc8568089)" but I do not know how to apply it for different ranges. please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If $0<x \le100  , D =2$
> if $100<x \le200  , D =5.3$
> if $200<x \le300  , D =1.2$

We can denote each range of values for $x$ as binary variables $u_1, u_2$, and $u_3$ with the following constraint

$$u_1 + u_2 + u_3 =1$$

Then, we will need another constraint that represents $x$ with:
$$x\le 100u_1 + 200u_2 + 300u_3$$
$$x > 0u_1 + 100u_2 + 200u_3$$
or, if we don’t want $x$ to be as free (in that we want the value for $x$ to determined by the picked ranges, and not by $x$ itself), then

$$x=100u_1 + 200u_2 + 300u_3$$

Lastly, our objective function will then become the following:
$$D=2u_1 + 5.3u_2 + 1.2u_3$$

Here’s [supplemental material](https://homepages.rpi.edu/%7Emitchj/handouts/piecewise/) that talks about modeling piecewise functions.

Comment: Thank you very much. I just want to add that I only needed                                                                                   
                                                                                                             
    ≤1001+2002+3003;
 
    >=01+1002+2003 (added equality to this one)                                                            
                                                                                                                                              
 and it totally worked.

Comment: @SiIs That would invalidate the lower bound constraints tho. If you want to have an equality for that second constrain, you can introduce a constant $\epsilon=0.00000001$ and then do the following: $$x\ge\epsilon u_1 + (100+\epsilon)u_2+(200+\epsilon)u_3$$ with epsilon being any very small number you choose such that $x$ will never be exactly those lower bound values. Without that, it’s possible for $u_2=1$ with $x=100$ which shouldn’t be allowed